# Warning on using getline() in C

Tags: c

```
int bytes_read;
int nbytes = 100;
char *Name;

Name = (char *) malloc (nbytes + 1);
bytes_read = getline (&Name, &nbytes, stdin);

/* Warning Message when compiled
   warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int *' to
   parameter of type 'size_t *' (aka 'unsigned long *')
   [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   ...bytes_read = getline (&Name, &nbytes, stdin);
                                   ^~~~~~~
*/
```

I am trying to use getline() function in C. It ran good when compiled but there is a warning. 
Why there is a warning? I cant figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second argument `&nbytes` of `getline` you are passing to is of type `int *` but `getline` expects second argument of type `size_t *`.
Change the declaration

```
int nbytes = 100;
```

to

```
size_t nbytes = 100;
```

<strike>or you can cast the second argument as</strike>

```
bytes_read = getline (&Name, (size_t *)&nbytes, stdin);
```

(For `int nbytes = 100;`, never cast `&nbytes` to `size_t *`)

Comment: *Do not* cast an `int*` to `size_t*`. If `int` and `size_t` happen to be of different sizes (or have incompatible representations), that's a recipe for disaster. It will silence the compiler warning, and worse it will appear to work on many systems.

Comment: @KeithThompson; What when casting `int *` type to `double *`? I did this many time!

Comment: Why on Earth would you cast an `int*` to a `double*`? `int` and `double` are very likely to be of different sizes; they certainly have different representations.

Comment: @KeithThompson; When can we use cast? I think I am understanding something wrong about casting in C.

Comment: Say you have an object `int n;`. Its address `&n` is of type `int*`. You can cast that address to `double*`: `(double*)&n`, and dereferencing that pointer `*(double*)&n` gives you an object of type `double` -- but you never created an object of type `double`. If, say, `int` is 32 bits and `double` is 64 bits, then `*(double*)&n` is a `double` object occupying the space for `n` plus 32 bits of otherwise unallocated space. Explain to me why you'd want to do that.

Comment: @KeithThompson; Thanks a lot. I need to do some homework on casting. :)

Answer (score 2):

The second argument to the `getline` function (which is defined by POSIX but not by ISO C, BTW) is of type `size_t*`. Passing an argument of type `int*`, as you're doing, is a *constraint violation*, requiring a compile-time diagnostic. A compiler may (and IMHO should) reject the call as a fatal error; gcc chooses to issue a mere warning by default.

Your code, if it compiles, causes `getline` to attempt to treat an `int` object as if it were a `size_t` object. This may happen to "work" if `int` and `size_t` happen to be the same size on your system. If they're not, arbitrary bad things can happen -- including your program appearing to work "correctly" until it blows up at the most inconvenient possible moment.

Define `nbytes` as a `size_t` object, not as an `int`. (Don't even think about casting the pointer from `int*` to `size_t*`; that will silence the warning, and your code *might* still appear to "work", but it will not solve the problem.)

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter for `getline()` is of type `size_t`, not `int`:

```
ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream)
```

`size_t` is an `unsigned long` that's used to represent "sizes" (which can't be less than `0`). It's an implicit cast from `int` to `size_t` and your code should execute fine as long as you never pass in a negative value. However, I would recommend updating it to use `size_t` instead:

```
ssize_t bytes_read;
size_t nbytes = 100;
```

Comment: The OP's code has a constraint violation, so a compiler is free to reject it (gcc chooses to treat it as a non-fatal error). And if `int` and `size_t` are of different sizes, it can fail in arbitrarily bad ways. He's not passing an `int`, he's passing a pointer to an `int` object.

Answer (score 0):

The warning explains it rather clear - you are using incompatible types. `int *` and `unsigned long *` are quite different, but the compiler will do a cast and just warns you that you can lose some data, e.g. when passing signed data like `-2`